# how to make a general shell to run all C programs without specifying the name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know I have  to take the path first and then run the code like export :$PATH but how do i feed the name of the program to the script?

I have tried to use the command line arguments and try to execute it but it's a dead end.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question; at the moment, it's not clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a shell script such that i can  feed in a "name" of a C file and make it run 
unlink gcc "file"
i want to feed file name as a variable @TomFenech

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you mean and provide us with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first command line argument in the variable `"$1"`, the second with `"$2"`, etc.

To iterate over all the arguments, use

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    do_something_with "$arg"
done
```